# Get the results returned from an NSInvocationOperation

Tags: ios, nsinvocation, nsinvocationoperation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];        
    NSInvocationOperation *downloadImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[ImageDownloader getInstance]
                                                                            selector:@selector(downloadImageSync:)
                                                                              object:@"image url"];
    [operationQueue addOperation:downloadImageOperation];        
    UIImage *imag = [downloadImageOperation result]; // image is always nil here
    imageVIEW.image = imag;
}
```

**Returns the result of the invocation or method.
- (id)result
Return Value
The object returned by the method or an NSValue object containing the return value if it is not an object. If the method or invocation is not finished executing, this method returns nil.**

I always get `nil` for the image.
What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations on a `NSOperationQueue` are executed on a separate thread. The operation has not finished executing when you call `[downloadImageOperation result]`, therefore the result is `nil`.

You can for example assign the image view at the end of your `downloadImageSync:` method, but it must be done on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageVIEW.image = imag;
});
```